# pulling gitlab repository without password that is not under my profile but have full access to

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have full access (maintainer) to gitlab repository that is not under my profile. I am trying to pull that repository using ssh-key on to my linux server, it asks for git@IP password. Is there any way that can I pull without password. It works fine without password for repositories that are created under my profile but not for repositories that are under different profile. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was I was trying to git clone to a directory that I didn't have permission to. I was using sudo for https link which worked perfectly fine. I made the assumption, it should work for ssh link as well but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Check first your identity, as seen by GitLab

```
ssh -Tv git@IP
```

That way, you can compare it with the [list of members](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/) for your other project (the one not under your profile), and confirm if that username is indeed listed.